# Dragon NaturallySpeaking 11 installer on wine gets stuck

Tags: wine, speech-recognition

So I am trying to install Dragon Naturally Speaking 11 on Wine but at the installation I manage to get only at the last point of the setup where it is stuck for more than an hour

[image: screenshot of the installer]

What should I do now? I believe clicking cancel will rollback changes but that seems to be the only thing remaining, or I can just kill this process and trying installing it over again, it might get over with this step. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer is still stuck where it was but I can see it appear under the Wine menu and from there I can run it. So, I just killed all the wine related processes and all looks good now.